# Which type of statistical analysis to run in R with 2 treatment types in my study?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, anova, manova

[Screenshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr4tA.png)
I have a seed germination study that I am trying to analyze. In this study I had 4 different media types (nutritious agar plus different vitamins/additives) with 40 plates each. Each group of 40 plates was split into 5 groups of 8 plates to further test sterilization/scarification pretreatment times (10, 30, 60, 90, 120 minutes). The resulting germination of all seed per plate was counted into 6 different stages of growth (stages 0-5, stage 0 representing no germination of the seed).I used Excel to show me the percent germination per plate (stages 1-5). Technically stages 3-5 are more important, but I am just looking at the ability to germinate so for the sake of this study stages 1-5 are fine to group together to give the binary of yes or no on germination. My question is what statistical test should I be running in R? I've included a screenshot of my data.

I've played around with Python before deciding to use R. At the end of the day, I've realized that I just don't know which test I should be running: ANOVA, 2-Way ANOVA, MANOVA, etc... My stats skills have a ways to go, this is me trying to learn.

Comment: Statistical questions like "what test should I run" are a better fit a stats.stackexchange.com . If you know what you want to do but are having trouble coding it, that's a good programming question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree that this question is better suited to stats.stackexchange, but if you are asking a question about R, please don't share your data as an image - it's easier for others to help if you include a sample of your data with `dput()`.